# Display an image in the form of an int array [] in an ImageView

Tags: android, arrays, android-imageview

How do I display an image in `int [] format`, for example:

```
int[] UM = {1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1};
```

here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView imageTeste;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int[] UM = {1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1};
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(UM, 5, 9, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        imageTeste = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageId);
        imageTeste.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

But it does not display anything, only if I change the Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 parameter to RGB_565, but doing it, the white pixels (1) turn black. Even converting values (1) to 255 does not work, they are displayed as blue.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: i guess, you want to convert bytearray to image.

Answer (score 0):

The method you're using is: `Bitmap createBitmap (int[] colors, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config)`. Take a look at the documentation for this method [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29). The `int[]` you supply the method must be an array of Color ints. These are not regular integers and using a 0 or 1 for these values is what is making your image appear empty.

Check out the Android docs on Color [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html).

For example, opaque blue would be `0xff0000ff`. Color ints have 4 components packed in a single 32 bit integer value. The 4 components represent Alpha, Red, Green, and Blue respectively. In the example the A component is `FF` meaning color is fully opaque. The R component `00`, there's no red. The G component is `00`, there's no green. The B component is `FF`, all blue.

You'll just need to give the `createBitmap()` method a valid `int[]` and you should solve your problem.